# Projects fail to open on Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just added some plugins to intellijIdea version 14.0.1, on restarting it, non of  my projects could load.

This is the error message

```
Cannot load project: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/intellij/atg/jsp/OpenDspInclude.registerTags(Lcom/intellij/psi/PsiReferenceProvider;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/intellij/psi/filters/position/NamespaceFilter;[Ljava/lang/String;)V @19: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type 'com/intellij/psi/impl/source/resolve/reference/ReferenceProvidersRegistry' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/intellij/psi/PsiReferenceRegistrar'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @19
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/intellij/atg/jsp/OpenDspInclude', 'com/intellij/psi/PsiReferenceProvider', 'java/lang/String', 'com/intellij/psi/filters/position/NamespaceFilter', '[Ljava/lang/String;' }
    stack: { 'com/intellij/psi/impl/source/resolve/reference/ReferenceProvidersRegistry', '[Ljava/lang/String;', 'com/intellij/psi/filters/ScopeFilter', 'com/intellij/psi/PsiReferenceProvider' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab4 001c 04bd 0031 5903 2c53 2d19 04b8
    0000010: 004f 2bb8 0055 b1                      
 [Plugin: OpenDSPInclude]
```

Comment: Why don't you contact their support? They have excellent support via email. You should also try disabling plugins one by one until you find out exactly which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks alot thatidiotguy, apparently, it was the OpenDSPInclude plugin, it is even listed at the bottom of the error message. I will try to find out why, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps someone could add the above as an answer and tick it as accepted so that this question is removed from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have installed plugins which are not compatible With IntelliJ. You have to 
uninstall them.

In my case, it was the Gradle Gui Plugin.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen due to plugin incompatibility.
Please check if your intellij version is supported by plugin.
Meanwhile to get access to your projects you can disable the plugin.

Comment: apparently so..the plugin in this case is no longer supported.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue in Android studio, Have fixed with following steps

Open Android studio Welcome screen. Then take preference from Android Studio menu then
Android studio -> Preference -> Plugins

Now you can see a sorting menu in top with a text "show". 
On there Select "Custom" plugin, now please uninstall all the custom plugin you have installed.

Now restart your Android studio, It will work

**If still exist issues. Please backup and remove Android studio preference folder**.

**in Windows** should be in c:\user\yourname.AndroidStudio2.1

**in Linux** should be in /home/yourname/.AndroidStudio2.1

**in Mac** should be in ~/Library/Preferences/.AndroidStudio2.1

Now restart your studio with another preference, still, you can navigate and reuse your old Android SDK.